# the argument type "object" cant be assigned to the parameter type String - error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

**I have a problem with the model flutter project that I have. I get an error:**

the argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
the argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
        itemHeight: 50,
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
        onChanged: (dynamic value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedCategory = value;
          });
        },
        onSaved: (dynamic value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedCategory = value;
          });
        },
        value: selectedCategory,
        hint: Text('Select Category'),
        items: categories.map((f) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(f), //here is the error showing like : the argument type 'categoryData'  cant be assigned to the parameter type String
            value: f,
          );
        }).toList()));
```

**category data section**

```
class CategoryData {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  String? image;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;

  CategoryData({this.id, this.name, this.image, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});

  factory CategoryData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CategoryData(
      id: json[CommonKeys.id],
      name: json[CategoryKeys.name],
      image: json[CategoryKeys.image],
      createdAt: json[CommonKeys.createdAt] != null ? (json[CommonKeys.createdAt] as Timestamp).toDate() : null,
      updatedAt: json[CommonKeys.updatedAt] != null ? (json[CommonKeys.updatedAt] as Timestamp).toDate() : null,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson({bool toStore = true}) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data[CommonKeys.id] = this.id;
    data[CategoryKeys.name] = this.name;
    data[CategoryKeys.image] = this.image;
    data[CommonKeys.createdAt] = this.createdAt;
    data[CommonKeys.updatedAt] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Which line does this error occur? Seems like you are passing an `Object?` into a method that expects a `String`

Comment: try Text(f.toString())

Comment: `Text` needs a string, and you are passing an object. I assume you want to see `name` of category, so change like: `child: Text(f.name)`. Besides it is a good idea to set the type of data that your dropdown handles like `DropdownButtonFormField<CategoryData>`.

Comment: it is not showing the categories from firebase. i have changed text(f.tostring()) and text(f.name.tostring())....both method doesnt fetching the category list data from firebase